# C# (Aforge.Video) MJPEGStream and high disk space consuming

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, stream, ip-camera

I have following code:

```
        MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream("http://192.168.88.252/cgi-bin/mjpeg?resolution=1920x1080&quality=1&page=1517608886020&Language=0");

        stream.NewFrame += Stream_NewFrame;
        stream.Start();
```

and

```
 private void Stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame.Clone() as Bitmap;

            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Is there any chance that the stream is leaking? I realized that disk space on C drive (Windows) is disapearing very quick. I know that is possible by stream, but how to clear reference or clear that data from temp files? GC.Collect seems to be not working. If I close the stream all that space is back again. I'm stuck at this problem...

I found 4 files in location C:\Windows\Temp that named httC18F.tmp, httBD96.tmp, httC411.tmp, httBDE5.tmp and there are increasing itself weight (starts at 31 MB per file, then after while 255 MB...)

Comment: Is the issue the disk space or your process' memory? Because GC.Collect has nothing to do with your disk space...

Comment: Only the disk space, process memory is at the same level

Comment: Have you looked for pieces of code that would write actually anything on the disk? Because from the code you provide, there is no proof that anything would "leak" on the disk.

Comment: Yes, I just made simple solution with only that code (in WinForms Form.Designer.cs) and the problem is still there...

Comment: Have you investigated which files are leaking on the disk?

Comment: I found 4 files in location C:\Windows\Temp that named httC18F.tmp, httBD96.tmp, httC411.tmp, httBDE5.tmp and there are increasing itself weight (starts at 31 MB per file, then after while 255 MB...)

Comment: @Kzrystof any ideas? : / Those files are growing up completely running out disk space

Comment: You start looking into the MJPEGStream class...

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose the current Image you have in the picture box before replacing it, this way :

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Please ensure to have a default Image in your picturebox first to avoid Image to be null at the very first frame.